# Rails 4 Grape API ActionController::RoutingError

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-grape

I am trying to make a Grape API answering in json format to all its verbs. The problem is that I can't make it answer to a routing error in json format. I even can't rescue the ActionController::RoutingError.

I have read this link https://github.com/intridea/grape/pull/342 and I've put the cascade directive to false but the API only answers "Not Found" in plain text.

```
$ curl -X GET http://localhost:3000/api/wrong_uri
Not Found
```

with verbose option:

```
$ curl -X GET http://localhost:3000/api/wrong_uri -v
* About to connect() to localhost port 3000 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
> GET /api/wrong_uri HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: localhost:3000
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 
< Content-Type: text/html
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< X-Request-Id: 3cc74a78-3295-4c1f-b989-66d6fac50e5c
< X-Runtime: 0.002980
< Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.1.1/2014-02-24)
< Date: Tue, 06 May 2014 05:46:33 GMT
< Content-Length: 9
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
Not Found
```

My grape file /app/api/api.rb

```
module API
  class Base < Grape::API
    format :json
    default_error_formatter :json
    cascade false

    rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |e|
      Rack::Response.new({ error: "Forbidden", detail: "Access denied", status: '403' }.to_json, 403).finish
    end

    # it doesn't catch ActionController::RoutingError
    # rescue_from :all do |e|
    #   error_response({ message: "rescued from #{e.class.name}" })
    # end

    helpers ApiHelpers

    mount API::Auth
    mount API::V2
    mount API::V1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By specifying `cascade false` you're saying Grape should be allowed to handle HTTP errors without interference from Rails. Consequently, when an unmatched URI beneath your API's mount point is requested, no `ActionController::RoutingError` is generated (this *would* have been done by Rails) and instead the output from Grape's default "unmatched route" handler is returned verbatim. Somewhat unhelpfully, this handler generates a plain "Not Found" message even when `format :json` has been specified, and that is the behaviour you're seeing.

The solution is to provide your own matchers to catch routes other than those specified in your `V1` and `V2` modules. Try adding this code to `API::Base` *beneath* the three `mount` statements:

```
# Generate a properly formatted 404 error for all unmatched routes except '/'
route :any, '*path' do
  error!({ error:  'Not Found',
           detail: "No such route '#{request.path}'",
           status: '404' },
         404)
end

# Generate a properly formatted 404 error for '/'
route :any do
  error!({ error:  'Not Found',
           detail: "No such route '#{request.path}'",
           status: '404' },
         404)
end
```

Naturally you'll want to edit the body of each `route` block to suit your needs.

For some reason both blocks seem to be necessary to catch all unmatched routes; this is a limitation of either Grape's matcher syntax or my understanding.